# How to intercept http status code 401 with angular 2?

Tags: spring, angular, authentication, http-status-code-401, intercept

How can I intercept the "401 authorization required" in an angular 2 application with spring then redirect the user to the login page?

For example once I try to access a page if I am not connected. the interceptor must oblige me to connect. And I want this interceptor to listen to all 401 status returned by the server.

Comment: use Angular [Http Interceptors](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/services)

Comment: You can use `ng2-interceptors`. https://github.com/voliva/angular2-interceptors

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any outside packages you can simply create your own rest http service.

All you need to do is to create a service class that extends Http.

Example:

```
export class RestHttp extends Http {

constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend) {
  super(backened, new RequestOptions (...))
}

get(url: string) {
  return this.catchError(super.get(url));
}

(delete, post, put) (...)

private catchError(res: Observable<Response>) {
  return res.catch((err) => {
    if (err.status >= 400) {
       *your logic*
    }
    return Observable.throw(err);
  });
}
```

Now you have to provide it inside your module. Something like this:

**app.module**

```
(...)
providers: [
  {provide: Http, useFactory: httpFactory, deps: [...]
(...)

export function httpFactory(backend: XHRBackend) {
   return new RestHttp(...)
}
```